# Multiple heavens

Tags: jannah, jahannam

Referring to [Is the "distance of 500 years" mentioned in the hadiths, a distance of walking?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/80948/55518), I am looking for sources that state that there are multiple heavens.

In Christian folklore, there are seven heavens and seven hells, but that is folklore only, not canonical.

I like to know what the Quran and the Hadith tell about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are seven heavens. It is a canonical belief and you can use a search engine to find the term muliple times within the Quran:

> الله الذي خلق سبع سماوات
>
> It is Allah who has created seven heavens
>
> <sup>— [Quran 65:12](https://quran.com/65/12?translations=20)</sup>

Note however that here 'heavens' means skies and not paradise. Although paradise and hell also do have multiple levels.

Comment: Quote: "It is Allāh who has created seven heavens and of the earth, the like of them." I don't quite understand, are there seven earths, too? Never heard of that, but then I don't speak the Arabic language and cannot translate for myself.

Comment: I cannot accept an answer unless I can understand it.

Comment: That is your choice. But what don't you understand about it? You asked if there are multiple heavens and I answered Yes and gave you a reference for that. You are now asking a new question in the comments if there are also seven earths in Islam. This is a very trivial question which you can easily lookup on this site or on other Islamic sites and resources (even multiple heavens is a trivial question but I answered it because of the confusion between heavens and paradise).

Comment: OK, I see and accept your reason that this is a different question.